# How to enable .NET Core 3 preview features in VS Code on Mac

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have installed the latest version of .NET Core 3 for MacOS from the official [site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0) to test the latest features of [C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8), however when I try to use some of the features like `readonly-members`, `switch expressions`, `property patterns`, `using declarations` I get a compile time error telling me that I should enable the **preview**:

```
    The feature 'readonly members' is currently in Preview and
    *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' 
    language version. (CS8652) [MiscellaneousFiles.csproj]
```

I have already modified the .csproj file to use the preview:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

And with that change some features work like `default interface members`. So I have a couple of questions:

Am I missing something?

Are some features not released yet, and if so why do they include them in the page of C# 8 features?

Did I get a corrupted installation of .NET Core 3?

Comment: It's not an answer to the overall question you're after (I've wondered the same for other preview features) but for the specific example of readonly members, you can get mostly the same effect by using `public object Foo {get;}` instead of `public readonly Foo {get; set;}`